# Why does the HTML editor not wrap my code in paragraph tags when I press enter

Tags: html, visual-editor

Normally when using a rich text editor, when you hit return (i.e. do a full paragraph return) Your text is wrapped i.e. `<p> my text </p>` however this does not happen in wordpress.

Is there any way to trigger this functionality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This happens at the time the content is output the browser. At that point, the content is passed through several filters, one of which is called `wpautop`. This filter function is defined in `wp-includes/formatting.php`. In combination with the other default WordPress filters, this generally means that you can compose content in the HTML (non-wysiwyg) editor as if you were writing plain text, and it will format the final HTML output in a logical, intuitive manner.

On the other hand, you can also feel free to manually compose HTML tags in your output, and WP will preserve your tags. There are some edge-cases that can get you sometimes (using non-standard tags or attributes), but for the most part, the editor and the filters are pretty smart.

Comment: yes - apparently the get_the_content function does not filter the content using wpautop I had to do: apply_filters('the_content', get_the_content());